# How to set Google Apps Engine appcfg to use SSH tunnel?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, ssh-tunnel, appcfg

I set a ssh tunnel using putty and configured windows setting and Firefox proxy to browse the internet through it. It works perfectly.
Now I want to upload my GAE app via the same ssh tunnel.
What do I have to do to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you could get a software that would **socksify** the app you need to use the tunnel (socks proxy), google some of these for more details:

- SocksCap
- FreeCap
- WideCap
- etc...