# how to update a GAE app with GCLOUD via socks5 proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

i created my GAE app in development console. i use to update it using appcfg.

now i am behind a socks5 proxy, and couldnt find the way to set appcfg to go through.

can someone reply all the steps to do it please ?
could be using appcfg or gcloud tools

thank you very much

Comment: How is this different from [your yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646879/)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use accpcfg or gcloud behind a proxy by setting the `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables. For example, on windows:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
```

and on linux/osx:

```
export http_proxy="http://cache.mycompany.com:3128"
export https_proxy="http://cache.mycompany.com:3128"
```

Here is some documentation about this:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Using_an_HTTP_proxy

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. As i understand, socks != http proxies as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Comparison_to_HTTP_proxying. Any idea ?